# Kinesis Kafka Source Connector - Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, amazon-kinesis

I am working on a POC using Confluent platform and trying to connect Kinesis in my AWS account to send data to Kafka running on Confluent platform (setup using Docker compose). I have used the AWS Kinesis connector available with Confluent. I am using trial version of the connector valid for 30 days.

I have setup the KinesisSourceConnector plugin from https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-kinesis

The Source connector configuration has credentials configuration available for AWS Access Key Id, AWS Secret Key Id
However, it does not have a configuration parameter for AWS Session Token. Is there any way to set this up since my AWS account can only be accessed using STS ?

I have tried adding an additional property aws_access_key_id but with no success.

Error description -
The provided credentials are invalid: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: d893039b-d4f3-4de3-95ef-ede233b0885c)

Comment: Please show how you added your AWS credentials (ideally, these are not done in the connector itself)

Comment: I added them using the Confluent control center in the Connector settings. 
AWS Credentials
AWS Access Key Id
AWS Secret Key Id

Please let me know how I can configure the credentials

Comment: Like I said, they shouldn't be added as connector configs. You should add environment variables to the Connect server's Java process instead for security reasons, or have `~/.aws/credentials` file on the Connect worker servers

Comment: thanks for the help @OneCricketeer 
I added these to the docker-compose.yml file and set up env variables for my aws credentials. Now it works .. appreciate your help !! 

      AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: '${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}'
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}'
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}'
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: '${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @OneCricketeer for helping find an answer

Add environment variables to the Connect server's Java process for security reasons, or have ~/.aws/credentials file on the Connect worker servers

1. Create a .env file in the folder where you will run Kafka connect
2. Setup the aws credentials in the .env file (AWS_SESSION_TOKEN, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
3. Modify the docker-compose yml file to add the environment variables
   for Kafka connect

```
connect:
    image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.5.3-7.1.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"

    environment:
      ...
      AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: '${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}'
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}'
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}'
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: '${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}'
```

4. Restart Kafka connect